Is it more secure to change a forgotten password with a token or to send a one-time password in plain text?
I inherited web software where the forgotten password page sends a new password to the user by email. I plan to change that and I am now searching for arguments why one of the two methods below (or something else) could be better in terms of security.

Option 1: Temporary Password

Create a random password
Save the salted hash in the database with an expiry time
Send the plain password to the user in an email and forget it
Force the user to change the password after the next login. Make sure the new password is different from the one that was sent.

Option 2: Token

Create a link with a random token that has a limited lifetime
Send the link to the user by email
The user is authenticated by the token and can set a new password


I tend towards Option 2 with the following arguments:

It feels more natural to limit the lifetime of a token than that of a password. That argument is more about usability but it might increase acceptance among users (not all will understand why to take the extra step via a temporary password) and therefore increase security.
If the "forgotten password" procedure was initiated by an unauthorized person, the legitimate user can still log in with the original password. I see it as security-relevant because locking out another user with a known email address could be an attack
Similarly: It is easier to invalidate a token than a password if needed.

Note: I won't use MFA/2FA at this stage because users might not yet have set it up. Encrypted emails are no option here.

You are right, that the token based method is the better approach. You already mentioned these problems:

Anybody can do a password forgotten request, and it would make the current password invalid. Doing so repeatedly could prevent a user from login.
The token can have a limited timespan, a new password could not.

Here are some other thoughts:

The new password is available in an e-mail, if an attacker can read the e-mail in future, (s)he can access the account and the user wouldn't be aware of it. It is enough to have a glimpse at the mails when the device was kept unlocked for a short time, no hacking would be necessary.
The same goes for unused reset tokens, if they can be used years later, readonly access to the e-mails is all an attacker needs. That's why the tokens should expire (though the timespan doesn't have to be extremely short).

Don't forget to hash the token before writing it into the database, otherwise an attacker with read only access to the db (SQL-injection) can request a password reset and afterwards read the token and use it. The hash can be an unsalted one in this case (e.g. SHA-256), because the token itself is not a weak user generated password, rather a (hopefully) long random key.

Thanks, I agree. To make both options equivalent, I would also limit the lifetime of the email. For the token I would use a JWT, which makes it easier to validate it.
